# No such module ZFDragableModalTransition in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a xCode project. I am trying to run [FolioReaderKit](https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReaderKit). I've installed the all project requirements such as [CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods) and [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) and I've fixed the errors except [ZFDragableModalTransition](https://github.com/dimohamdy/ZFDragableModalTransitionSwift).

I've downloaded it and added into my project over and over, I've added it as a Link Binary but I'm still getting same error. "No such module ZFDragableModalTransition in Swift"
I am very new in swift and Xcode therefore I might be make a mistake but I didn't manage it yet. 
Do you have any suggestion?

You can see the error attached images.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run the FolioReaderKit Example project and you are new to Swift and Xcode I suggest you to use Cocoapods instead of Carthage. You don't have to run `FolioReaderKit.xcodeproj`.

Just go to Example folder and follow this steps:

1. Open the Terminal on `Example` folder;
2. Run `pod install` (you need Cocoapods installed);
3. Open `Example.xcworkspace` file on your Xcode and run;

To add this you your project using Cocoapods create a `Podfile` and add:

```
use_frameworks!
target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'FolioReaderKit', '~> 0.7'
end
```

Then use `pod install` to install it to your project, the usage documentation is in the Example project.

Comment: Great. That has solved my problem. Thank you so much Heberti.